# Include vs Input in my case

Tags: bibliographies, appendices, input, include

Suppose you have two fully finished thesis, with their own bibliography and their own appendices. When I include one into the other, there is (obviously) some interference between the two different bibliographies and two different appendices.

So my question is: what is the optimal solution so that I get only one bibliography and one appendix. Also, I would like the included file to consist of one large section with subsections and not as it is at the moment, which is: each sections of the included file gets a section of its own.

Happy for any advice.

Comment: You might need to give more information about the structure of your documents, a latex document can only have one `\documentclass` so you can't include or input one in to another. If each document consists of `\including` a list of separate section files, you can of course make a combined document but including the combined set of sections, but without knowing the structure it is not possible to say much.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Not a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include, in spite of the misleading title, that should be something like _How to combine two complete theses in a document?_, since neither `\input` nor `\include` solve the real question.

Answer (score 1):

As David Carlisle said, it is not possible say much with the actual information, but I suspect that you are looking for the  `combine` class  and the packages `combinet`, `combnat` and `combcite`.

With `texdoc combine` you will obtain all the information of what you need at this respect.

If this is not exactly what you want, take a look also to the  packages `docmute` and `standalone` (the package, not the document class!).